# How to Mail Enable an AD Group with VB.net

Tags: vb.net, active-directory, exchange-server-2010

I have written a program in VB that uses GroupPrincipal to create Active Directory groups, and populate them with users (and or other groups as necessary).

Can anyone give me pointers on how to get these groups mail-enabled on our exchange2010 server via the same program please?

I've seen (in my googleing) some powershell you can run on the server itself, but I need for my program to automatically enable these groups as they are created.

Hoping someone can get me on the right track.
Pete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Private Sub CreateDistributionList()

```
    Dim ad As DirectoryEntry

    Dim contacts As DirectoryEntry

    Dim entry As DirectoryEntry



    ' Create a conntaction to Active Directory

    ad = New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://MACHINENAME/DC=DOMAIN,DC=COM", "username", "password")

    ' Find the OU to create the contact in

    contacts = ad.Children.Find("OU=Distrubtion Lists")



    ' Create AD object

    entry = contacts.Children.Add("CN=LastName\, FirstName", "group")



    ' Fill out basic attributes

    entry.Properties("groupType").Value = 8 ' 8 = Universal Group

    entry.Properties("displayName").Value = "Name"

    entry.Properties("sAMAccountName").Value = "Name" ' I don't know if this is required

    entry.Properties("mail").Value = "EmailAddress@Something.com"

    entry.Properties("telephoneNumber").Value = "555-555-5555"

    entry.Properties("description").Value = "description"



    ' The follow attributes I believe to be the ones required for mail enabling

    ' (though I have not testing thoroughly to pinpoint exactly what is required)



    ' SMPT MUST be capitalized

    entry.Properties("targetAddress").Value = "SMTP:EmailAddress@Something.com"

    entry.Properties("proxyAddresses").Value = New Object() {"SMTP:EmailAddress@Something.com"}

    ' To find the legacyExchangeDN, copy value from an existing contact

    entry.Properties("legacyExchangeDN").Value = ""

    ' mailNickName can not have spaces

    entry.Properties("mailNickName").Value = New String("FirstNameLastName").Replace(" ", "")



    ' Commit Changes to Active Directory

    entry.CommitChanges()



    ' Close connections to Active Directory

    entry.Close()

    ad.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: While posting Answer, you should also explain how your code solves  a problem